# Executing code for a custom Django 404 page

Tags: python, django

I am getting ready to deploy my first Django application and am hitting a bit of a roadblock.  My base template relies on me passing in the session object so that it can read out the currently logged in user's name.  This isn't a problem when I control the code that is calling a template.

However, as part of getting this app ready to be deployed, I need to create a 404.html page.  I extended my base template just like I've done with my other pages, but I don't see a way to pass in the session object so that I can utilize it.  Is there a way to have Django call a custom method to render your 404 rather than just rendering your 404.html for you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to override the default view handler for the 404 error. Here is the documentation on how to create your own custom 404 view function:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: Just a note for other people: You need to define `handler404` in the urls.py in the root of your project, not in one of your apps.

Comment: It must be in the file `settings.ROOT_URLCONF` points to (which normally is in the root of your project, but doesn't have to be...)

Comment: I found this answer because that tutorial didn't make sense to me. Does the handler404 line go in the urls.py urlpatterns list? How does the syntax of it make any sense?

Comment: Answered myself - yes it does go in urls.py, and outside of the urlpaterns. And yes, it is a string that holds the name in the format that you would otherwise use in an import statement. I found these details surprising, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

Define your own 404 handler. See [Django URLs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/), specifically the part about [handler404](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#handler404).